# Fill data grid view from sql table

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, datagridview

I have four columns in `Datagridview`. I want to fill first two columns with data from sql database. I try to fill `Datagridview`. It not display data, but it generate rows.

This is my code:

```
getConnect()
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
        Conn.Close()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Conn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("EMPLOYEE")
        da.Fill(dt)
        ATCGRID.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
    End Try
```

Please check my code and give me solution...

Comment: Is AutogenerateColumns property set to true? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: `ATCGRID.AutoGenerateColumns = False` also same

Comment: also it's better practice to bind via a bindingsource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code .

```
getConnect()
Try
    Conn.Open()
    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE ORDER BY EMP_NAME ASC"
    Conn.Close()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Conn)
    Dim ds As new Dataset
    da.Fill(ds,"EMPLOYEE")
    ATCGRID.DataSource = ds.tables(0)
Catch ex As SqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
End Try
```

Comment: I see please give comment Conn.Close()

Comment: i commented.. Still same.. my datagridview have four columns. i want to fill only first two columns.

Comment: I see, Please Fill Property Columns DataPropertyName as Field Database, ex : Column1-DataPropertyName=EMP_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the `sub getConnect()` it worked perfectly. mine also worked.

```
Sub RefreshGrid()
 ' refresh the datagrid
  OpenConnect()

CmdSql.CommandText = "SELECT manager_id,manager_name FROM   tbl_Manager"
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    adp.Fill(ds)
    dgvMgr.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    'THIS MODULE WORKED JUST Please Fill Property Columns 
    'DataPropertyName as Field Database, 
    'Eg : Column1-DataPropertyName=manager_id and so on.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Public Sub OpenConnect()

```
    Try
        CmdSql.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()
        CmdSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

' this worked perfectly