# Filling DataGridView from DataSet issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm having trouble fill up my DataGridView. I have three bits of code which are underlined blue:

1. 'SqlDataAdapter'- It says "Type 'SqlDataAdapter' is not defined"
2. 'dgv'- It says "'dgv' is not declared"
3. 'SQLCon' - It says "'SQLCon' is not declared"

The code within my form:

```
    Public Class Form4
Dim SQL As New SQLControl

Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With DGVData
        SQL.SQLDS = Nothing
        .Rows.Clear()
        .ColumnCount = 3


        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Booking ID"
        .Columns(0).Width = 75
        .Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter


        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Payment Confirmation"
        .Columns(1).Width = 100
        .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Total Cost"
        .Columns(2).Width = 100
        .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter



    End With

    LoadBookingData()
End Sub
Private Sub LoadBookingData()
    Dim loadSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM booking"
    Dim LoadAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim LoadDataSet As New DataSet
    Dim RowsCount As Integer

    dgv.Rows.Clear()

    If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        SQLCon.open()
        LoadAdapter.fill(LoadDataSet, "GettingInfo").
        RowsCount = LoadDataSet.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows.Count
        If RowsCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox("There is no records", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Sorry")
            LoadDataSet.Reset()
            Con.Close()
        Else
            ' there are records !
            dvg.Rows.Add(RowsCount)
            For i As Integer = 0 To RowsCount - 1
                With dvg
                    .Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = LoadDataSet.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows(i).Item("bookingID")
                    .Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = LoadDataSet.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows(i).Item("paymentConfirmation")
                    .Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = LoadDataSet.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows(i).Item("totalCost")
                End With
            Next
        End If
        LoadDataSet.Reset()
        Con.Close()

    Else
        ' the connection is already open 
        LoadAdapter.fill(LoadDataSet, "GettingInfo").
       RowsCount = LoadDataSet.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows.Count
        If RowsCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox("There is no records", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Sorry")
            LoadDataSet.Reset()
            Con.Close()
        Else
            ' there are records !
            dvg.Rows.Add(RowsCount)
            For i As Integer = 0 To RowsCount - 1
                With dvg
                    .Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = LoadDataSet.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows(i).Item("bookingID")
                    .Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = LoadDataSet.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows(i).Item("paymentConfirmation")
                    .Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = LoadDataSet.Tables("GettingInfo").Rows(i).Item("totalCost")
                End With
            Next
        End If
        LoadDataSet.Reset()
        Con.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

My 'SQLControl.vb' which i think something has to do with it :

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Public Class SQLControl
         Private SQLCon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data        Source=JENNIFER\DDAP2015;Initial Catalog=zachtravelagency;Integrated Security=True;"}
         Private SQLcmd As SqlCommand
         Public SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter
         Public SQLDS As DataSet
```

Can someone highlight my errors please?

Comment: What is the name of your Grid in the form? You need to specify `SQL.SQLCon` as it belongs to the `SQLControl` class.  Also, for this `Dim LoadAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter` are you importing `System.Data.SqlClient` into your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things.

1. You need to import `System.Data.SqlClient` into your `Form` to use the following

   `Dim LoadAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter`
2. You are using `dgv.Rows.Clear()` in one place and then you are seen using `dvg.Rows.Add(RowsCount)` down the line. Why are you using `dgv` and `dvg` to refer the grid? What is the correct name of the Grid?
3. As you are using the `SQLCon` variable which is a **Private** member of `SQLControl` class, you need to
           a. First make it **Public** if you want to use it in Form
           b. use `SQL.SQLCon` when you are referring to the variable. 
   Like

   `If SQL.SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then`
4. Why do you even need this `SQL.SQLDS = Nothing` if you are not using the `SQLDS` variable?
5. Why do you need `Dim LoadAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter` and `Dim LoadDataSet As New DataSet` as you already have a `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet` declared in `SQLCOntrol` class? You can simply use `SQL. SQLDA` and `SQL.SQLDS` instead of `LoadAdapter` and `LoadDataSet`.
6. You have an extra `.` after the `SQL.SQLDA.Fill(SQL.SQLDS, "GettingInfo")`. Remove the extra `.` and try.
7. Also, I don't think the name of the table inside your `DataSet` will be `GettingInfo`. You might want to use `RowsCount = LoadDataSet.Tables("booking").Rows.Count`

There will be a lot of errors and you have a long way to go before this code starts working. You will find a ton of tutorials in the net, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436710/fill-data-grid-view-from-sql-table), teaching what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've done all of your changes and now I have got significantly less errors. Thanks. However I still have two errors. This: "SQL.SQLDA.Fill(SQL.SQLDS, "GettingInfo").
            RowsCount" is underlined blue. And says 'RowsCount' is not a member of 'Integer'.

Comment: You have an extra `.` after the `SQL.SQLDA.Fill(SQL.SQLDS, "GettingInfo")`. Remove the extra `.` and try